# Spreadsheet Scripts IFTTT

Tags: spreadsheet, ifttt

I added a spreadsheet script to to increment the value of a cell when the value of another cell is changed but the problem is that the script doesn't run if the value of the cell is changed by a service like IFTTT.

Is there a fix for that?

Comment: What is "a spreadsheet script" in this context?

Comment: This is really hard to advise about something that we’ve never laid eyes upon before, such as your script, or, like, any other details whatsoever.  But, my stab in the dark is that you’ll likely need to change your IFTTT action to something that doesn’t effect the spreadsheet change itself, but instead sends a message for your script to intercept and make the change on its behalf.  The message can be delivered in as basic a fashion as creating a new file in Dropbox that will appear on your computer where the script will run. That’s easy to set up. But more info is needed as we’re not psychic.